# Beginner problems with many input parameters

Tags: c#

Hi I am begginner in C#. I have this class.
Class class1 have many variables.

```
class class1
{
string variable1;
string variable2;
//...
string variable10
}
```

and class class2 with method doSomethig:

```
class class2
{
void doSomething(string s1, string s2, ..., string s10)
}
```

I use instace of class1 and class2 in class3.

```
class class3
{
class1 obj1 = new clas1();
class2 obj2 = new clas2();

//...
string result = obj.doSomething(obj1.variable1, obj1.variable2, ... , obj1.variable10)

}
```

Problem is I call in class3 method doSomething from class2 and the input parameters to the method doSomething are variables from class1.
I would like have less parameters in method doSomething. I think add variables from class1 in to the struct or in class. What is the best way ? Thank.

Answer (score 7):

Try passing the object ITSELF.

```
obj2.doSomething(obj1);
```

If you provide public access to get the variables then your method in class2 will be able to access the values and you'll release the strain on your method definition and calling.

Comment: An excellent idea with one caveat: the code sample as he's shown provides no modifier to the fields, so they are private by default. He'll need to make them either internal or public before doing so.

Comment: Sure, hence: "If you provide public access to get the variables"

Comment: Reading comprehension FTW. :)

Answer (score 3):

Would it be more appropriate to use a string array (string[] variables) instead of variable1, variable2, etc? Or a dictionary of some sort?

If class 1 only contains parameters for the function, another alternative is to pass the entire object to the function:

```
class class2 
{ 
   void doSomething(class1 c) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class class2
{
  void doSomething(class1 obj) {...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off you shouldn't be providing direct access to the fields in your class. As this looks like Java you should have get and set methods to access the fields:

```
public String getVariable1()
{
  return variable1;
}

public void setVariable1(String var1)
{
  variable1 = var1;
}
```

EDIT: As it's C# it should be:

```
public String Variable1
{
  get; 
  set;
}
```

Next to answer your question, the doSomething method in class2 can just take an instance of class1:

```
public String doSomething(Class1 class1Instance)
{
  // implementation of doSomething goes here and accesses class1Instance.getVariable1() -> getVariable10();
}
```

Comment: It's C#, not Java - and fields default to being private in C#.

Comment: Fair point. Just noticed the lower case s on his String declaration.

Comment: The C# tag and the first sentence of the question are both less subtle hints ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use structures to send that values:

```
struct Data
{
    public int Var01 { get; set; }
    public int Var02 { get; set; }
    // ...
    public int Var10 { get; set; }
}
```

And use those like this:

```
doSomething(new Data()
{
    Var01 = 1,
    Var02 = 2,
    Var10 = 10
});
```

Comment: Mutable structures are evil... and structures with lots of fields are generally discouraged too. What makes you think a structure is appropriate here?

Comment: I thought I could suggest just to aggregate all those parameters into a unique struture, to avoid method with many args; can you please point to a resource to learn more about mutable structures? thanks for your feedback, jon.